# convert result of varchar column value to comma deligma int type

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL statement:

```
(select top 1 [egrp_name] from [Enotify Group] where [egrp_id] in (a.grp_id) )
```

the value of `a.grp_id` is `'0,1145'` and i am getting error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0,1145' to data type int.
```

Can anybody tell me how can i change `'0,1145'` to `0,1145` in above case

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 [egrp_name] 
from [Enotify Group] 
where [egrp_id] in (cast(replace(grp_id, ',', '.') as decimal))
```

Comment: its not working, and why you replacing with  ',' with '.' i want to result like `0,1145`

Comment: What means *doesn't work*? If you want to convert a string to a number you need to convert the `,` to decimal `.` eventually.

Comment: no i don't want to convert string to number, i want to convert string to int list which are comma separated

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought it was a single number. Well, good luck with this - storing multiple values in one column is always a pain. You better change your DB structure if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, can't change structure, i am thinking about spiting grp_id by `,` and then call it in loop